# Can someone explain me the line in between ** ? I don't understand how the map is working

Tags: scala, dictionary

```
def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] = occurrences match {  
    case List() => List(List())
    case occ :: occs =>
        for {
            **occSub <- (0 to occ._2).map((occ._1, _)).toList**
            occsCombination <- combinations(occs)
            } yield (occSub :: occsCombination).filter(x => x._2 != 0)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.map((occ._1, _))` is short for `.map(i => (occ._1, i))`.

For each element between 0 and `occ._2`, it creates a `Tuple` as above. So this returns a list of tuples with the first element fixed and the second going from 0 to `occ._2`.

For example:

```
scala> val occ = (42,5)
occ: (Int, Int) = (42,5)

scala> (0 to occ._2).map(i => (occ._1, i)).toList
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((42,0), (42,1), (42,2), (42,3), (42,4), (42,5))

scala> (0 to occ._2).map((occ._1, _)).toList
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((42,0), (42,1), (42,2), (42,3), (42,4), (42,5))
```